# NSight Include files from another project

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nsight

I have been trying to get one Nsight project (project 1) to use some files from another Nsight project(2), and for the life of me can't get the project 1 to build!

I have tried referencing/setting include paths/building project 2 as lib etc but nothing lets me build project 1 without encountering some kind of error. At the moment I have reference project 2 and get "No rule to make target" error.

What is the best way (bar copying and pasting the source files) to include files from one project in another.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This writeup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575677/include-a-static-cuda-library-into-a-c-project/24618837#24618837) demonstrates

1. how to *include* a file from one project into another (the `test8lib.h` header
   file from the library project is being included into the main project)
2. how to make one project link to a library produced in another project. (the library produced in the library project is linked into the main project).